# Jquery load() not working in Firefox version 40.0.3 but works in chromium

Tags: jquery, function, firefox, load

I am trying to reload a div in the same page. My code works fine in Chromium but it doesn't reload the div in Firefox version 40.0.3. Kindly advise.

```
var path = window.location.href;
$("#divID").load(path + " #divID", function() {
  // something goes here
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors was logged in the console